# Get ID (not value) of selected ColdFusion radio button

Tags: coldfusion, radio-button

I've created a quiz in ColdFusion with questions in one table and answers in another; it's multiple choice and each answer is presented as a member of a radio group. I'm looping through my recordset, rsAnswers, to output the radio group. I need to get the database ID of the selected radio button for an Insert operation and can't figure it out.

Here's how I'm outputting the question and answers:

```
<h3>Question #<cfoutput>#Session.theQuestion#</cfoutput></h3>
<h3><cfoutput>#rsQuestion.rrqQuestion#</cfoutput></h3>
<ol type="A" id="answerList">
  <cfoutput query="rsAnswers">
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="theAnswers" id=#rsAnswers.ID#" value="#rsAnswers.rraValue#" />
        #rsAnswers.rraAnswer#</label>
    </li>
  </cfoutput>
</ol>
```

If I could retrieve the ID attribute of the selected radio button, I'd be fine, but I don't see a way to do that in CF. What am I missing?

TIA - Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you post the form over, CF only gives you the `value` of the selected radio button from the `form` scope.  If you need the ID, you should set it as the button value:

```
<input type="radio" name="theAnswers"
   id=#rsAnswers.ID#" value="#rsAnswers.ID#">#rsAnswers.rraAnswer#</label>
```

Comment: Although this isn't really what I was hoping for, this gave me an idea to I was able to implement. I set the value equal to a concatenation of the answers value and it's ID and then used string functions to extract what I needed for the Insert. Thanks @Henry.

Comment: Can you explain why? Typically, you submit the ID only and do a query if you need the associated "text".